# Serverless concurrent write access in Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, hpc

Are there any packages in Python that support **concurrent** writes on **NFS** using a **serverless** architecture?

I work in an environment where I have a supercomputer, and multiple jobs save their data in parallel. While I can save the result of these computations in separate files, and combine their results later, this requires me to write a reader that is aware of the specific way in which I split my computation across jobs, so that it knows how to stitch everything in a final data structure correctly.

Last time I checked **SQLite** did not support concurrency in **NFS**. Are there any alternatives to SQLite?

**Note:** By serverless I mean avoiding to explicitly start **another** server (on top of NFS) that handles the IO requests. I understand that NFS uses a client-server architecture, but this filesystem is **already** part of the supercomputer that I use. I do not need to maintain myself. What I am looking for is a package or file format that supports concurrent IO without requiring me to set-up any (additional) servers.

#### Example:

Here is an example of two jobs that I would run in parallel:

- **Job 1** populates `my_dict` from scratch with the following data, and saves it to `file` :

  `my_dict{'a'}{'foo'} = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`
- **Job 2** also populates `my_dict` from scratch with the following data, and saves it to `file`:

  `my_dict{'a'}{'bar'} = [0.1, 0.2]`

I want to later load `file`, and see the following in `my_dict`:

```
> my_dict{'a'}.items()
[('foo', [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]), ('bar', [2, 3, 5])]
```

Note that the stitching operation is automatic. In this particular case, I chose to split the keys in `my_dict['a']` across the computations, but other splits are possible. The fundamental idea is that there are no **clashes** between jobs. It implicitly assumes that jobs **add/aggregate** data, so the fusion of dictionaries (dataframes if using Pandas) always results in aggregating the data, i.e. computing an *"outer join"* of the data.

Comment: Your question is very confusing because you talk about NFS but then use the term 'serverless'. Since NFS always has a server, it doesn't make sense. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Thank you @Gabe - I have updated my OP to address your question.

Comment: So the Python script you want to write will write to a mounted NFS volume? In that arrangement your python script is the client (no extra servers needed :)

Comment: @JasonSperske correct.

Comment: This is an *extremely* difficult problem. You're not likely to find anything already written.

Comment: @Josh I agree with @Gabe, your requirements are too hard. If you would relax your "serverless" requirement, I would recommend trying e.g. Redis key-value store - it is fast, available for Linux as well Windows and is very easy to use with `redis` package. But it is definitely a server.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple DIY, potentially flaky

Hierarchical locking -- i.e. you lock `/` first, then lock `/foo` and unlock `/`, then lock `/foo/bar` and unlock `/foo`. Make changes to `/foo/bar` and unlock it.

This allows other processes access to other paths. Lock contention on `/` is relatively small.

### Complicated DIY

Adapt a lock-free or wait-free algorithm, e.g. RCU. Pointers become symlinks or files containing lists of other paths.

http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/rclock/intro/rclock_intro.html
https://dank.qemfd.net/dankwiki/index.php/Lock-free_algorithms